# Characters written in R become invisible after suspending and resuming job

Tags: linux, r, jobs

I have a recurrent problem when using R with a Linux console. I sometimes suspend it with `[Ctrl+Z]`, then put it to the background with `bg`, (execute some other commands), then put it to the foreground again with `fg`.

R resumes correctly with all the workspace intact, but when I type, the characters are invisible (just like when we type passwords).

I still can execute commands though, and I see the response. Moreover, when I type `[enter]`, the prompt doesn't go to the next line, but does something like this: `> > >`.

Then I need to quit R using `q()`, in order that everything returns to normal. I didn't manage to find any reference to this problem on internet.

Would you have an idea? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Did you change encodings in the mean time?

Comment: This often happens when you inadvertently send binary data to the terminal, or press an unlikely combination of keys. You can try to [reset](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-4.html) the terminal.

Comment: I did not change encodings, I actually just launched Konqueror and closed it. I tried to reset the terminal but it didn't change anything. Though, thanks to your comments I found that there is no problem when just suspending with `Ctrl+Z` and put to foreground with `fg` (without resuming job in the background). So I'll go with this solution and just don't do what hurts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direct answer but via

> "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this."
>
> "Then just don't do this."

I would suggest that if you must have an R console open, place it inside `screen` --- or if you have it, [byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) a fancier extensions, or even [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Or even inside the One True Editor (TM) using [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org).  For what it is worth, I always run `emacs --daemon` and then connect to the *same R session* either via `emacsclient -nw` on the terminal or under X11 via `emacsclient -c` (both of which I aliased to `emt` and `emx`).  I also run `byobu` sessions for command-line work where I often use [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) for command-line tasks and tests.

Unix is a multitasking system. There is no need to limit yourself to one prompt, especially if you suffer side-effects as a consequence.